# Calculated download speed is wrong when using TrafficStats class

Tags: java, android, networking, network-traffic

I want to build android download speed test. To do that I am using TrafficStats class. Problem is that I am getting wrong results. Results are almost the same when I run the test but I put heavy load on my Internet connection before I run test. I download file for 30 seconds and after that (or when file is downloaded) and then calculate bytes using TrafficStats

Does someone knows where is the problem?

This is code that I am using:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String downloaded ="";
           // String uploaded = "";
            try{

                long BeforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long TotalTxBeforeTest = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                long TotalRxBeforeTest = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection connection = new URL(urls[0]).openConnection();
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int n = 0;
                long endLoop = BeforeTime+30000;
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endLoop) {
                  /*  if (bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) != -1){
                        break;
                    }*/
                }
                long TotalTxAfterTest = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                long TotalRxAfterTest = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
                long AfterTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                double TimeDifference = AfterTime - BeforeTime;
                double rxDiff = TotalRxAfterTest - TotalRxBeforeTest;
                double txDiff = TotalTxAfterTest - TotalTxBeforeTest;
                Log.e(TAG, "Download skinuto. "+ rxDiff);
                if((rxDiff != 0) && (txDiff != 0)) {
                    double rxBPS = (rxDiff / (TimeDifference/1000)); // total rx bytes per second.
                    double txBPS = (txDiff / (TimeDifference/1000)); // total tx bytes per second.
                    downloaded = String.valueOf(rxBPS) + "B/s. Total rx = " + rxDiff;
                   // uploaded = String.valueOf(txBPS) + "B/s. Total tx = " + txDiff;
                }
                else {
                    downloaded = "No downloaded bytes.";
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while downloading. "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            return downloaded;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code - it seems to work fine for me BUT i changed

```
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endLoop) {
   /* if (bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
          break;
      }*/
}
```

to

```
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endLoop) {
    if (bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) == -1){
        break;
    }
}
```

since `read` returns `-1` if the end of the stream is reached.